# drag down hyperlink to change sheet name in hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, hyperlink

Want to create hyperlink as follow:

```
file:///E:\Satpuda Agritech\2016\072016.xlsm\'1M'!
file:///E:\Satpuda Agritech\2016\072016.xlsm\'2M'!
file:///E:\Satpuda Agritech\2016\072016.xlsm\'3M'!
```

when drag in excel where "072016.xlsm" is file name and 1M,2M,3M are sheet name

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `HYPERLINK` function:

`=HYPERLINK("file:///E:\Satpuda Agritech\2016\072016.xlsm\'"&ROW()&"M'")`

As you fill down the formula sheet name will be updated automatically.

[image]

Comment: Want to create link to worksheet in excel which drag down will change sheet in seqence

Comment: my answer creates the links exactly as in your example, if that isn't what you need, then please improve your question.

Comment: it creaet the link but it donot open file /sheet